# Work around in circular dependency

Tags: vb.net-2010, circular-dependency

Here's my question:

I have Project A which is referenced in Project B, but the problem is I also need to reference Project B in Project A. However, every time I try to do it there is an error which states that it cannot reference Project B to Project A because it will cause a circular dependency.

So can anyone suggest a workaround for my problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is generally a bad idea.  If there are some common things that might need to be shared by both assemblies, move it to a third assembly and have both projects reference that instead.